# Error in TFS Release Management Server after Upgrading to Update 3

Tags: tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

Some weird and unexplained error logged in InRelease aka (Release Management) server event log after upgrading Release Management Update 1 to update 3.

Below error started getting logged only after upgrading to Update 3.

Even though we started the Inrelease Server and all agents but no luck.

Any immediate help would be much helpful.

Timestamp: 12/15/2014 10:22:18 AM

**Message: 'LambdaValue>' is not of type 'ServerActivity'. When loading this instance you must ensure that the activity with name 'LambdaValue>' implements 'ServerActivity'.: \r\n\r\n   at**

System.Activities.ActivityInstance.System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityInstanceMap.IActivityReference.Load(Activity activity, ActivityInstanceMap instanceMap)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityInstanceMap.InstanceList.Load(Activity activity, ActivityInstanceMap instanceMap)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityInstanceMap.LoadActivityTree(Activity rootActivity, ActivityInstance rootInstance, List`1 secondaryRootInstances, ActivityExecutor executor)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.OnDeserialized(Activity workflow, WorkflowInstance workflowInstance)
   at System.Activities.Hosting.WorkflowInstance.InitializeCore(IDictionary`2 workflowArgumentValues, IList`1 workflowExecutionProperties)
   at System.Activities.Hosting.WorkflowInstance.Initialize(Object deserializedRuntimeState, DynamicUpdateMap updateMap)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.LoadCore(DynamicUpdateMap updateMap, TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper, Boolean loadAny, IDictionary`2 values)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.Load(Guid instanceId, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.Load(Guid instanceId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.ServiceProcessor.Processor.WorkflowInstance.WorkflowInstanceCacheSingleton.<.cctor>b__1(WorkflowApplication app, Guid id)
   at

Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.ServiceProcessor.Processor.WorkflowInstance.WorkflowInstanceCache.CreateApplicationInCache(CreateParameters createParameters, Guid id)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.ServiceProcessor.Processor.WorkflowInstance.WorkflowInstanceCache.GetInstance(CreateParameters createParameters, Guid id)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.ServiceProcessor.Processor.WorkflowInstance.CachedWorkflowInstanceLoader.GetInstance(DeploymentLog log, CreateParameters createParams)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.ServiceProcessor.Processor.DeploymentControllerServiceProcessor.ContinueDeploymentWithFinalComponentState(DeploymentLog log)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.ServiceProcessor.Processor.DeploymentControllerServiceProcessor.ContinueDeployment(String log)

Category: General

Priority: -1

EventId: 0

Severity: Error

Title:

Machine: **********

Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-1-130630102320068767

Process Id: 6628

Process Name: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe

Win32 Thread Id: 1344

Thread Name:

Extended Properties:

=============== Update (Solution) ==================
Issue/Error resolved after upgrading RM to Release Management 2015.

Comment: That looks like a bug and you should go ask it on the MSDN RM forum...https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=tfsbuild

Comment: Install Update 4 first -- it's possible you hit a problem that's already fixed.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Error gone after installing Release Management 2015.